# apply custom plotting function to list of features

Tags: python, function, for-loop, seaborn

I have created a function that creates a specified plot for a given feature:

```
def barplotter (dataset, feature):
  ax1 = sns.displot(dataset, x =feature,  stat = 'density', discrete = True, color = 'black')
  ax1.set(title=feature, xlabel = "")
  ax2 = sns.displot(dataset, x =feature, col = 'status_group', stat = 'density', discrete = True)
  ax2.set(xlabel = "")
  plt.show()
```

Result:

```
barplotter ( raw, "quality_group")
```

[image]

I would like to apply this function to a list of features instead of having to apply it manually for each features.

I was thinking of using a for loop.
First I created a list of features: `categorical_columns = raw[categorical].columns.tolist()`

```
for item in categorical_columns:
  barplotter(raw, item)
```

Unfortunately this results in an error
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in case anyone else runs into this error:

Some of my features consisted of mixed datatypes. I converted all features to strings and now the for loop works.